# jsp declaring and incrementing variables

Tags: jsp, rss

i have to display the rss feeds of websites through my jsp page here is the code.

```
<c:if test="${param.feedURL != null}">

<c:import var="xmlContent" url="${param.feedURL}"/>

<x:parse var="doc" xml="${xmlContent}"/>

<%! int i =1; %>
<table class="table table-condensed">
<th>
    <td colspan="2">
        <strong>Please select an item to set as message.</strong>
    </td>
</th>
 <x:forEach var="story"
            select="$doc/rss/channel/item" varStatus="status">
     <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="feedValue[]"  onclick="$('#message').val(this.value);" data-dismiss="modal" value="<x:out select="description" escapeXml="false"/>"></td>
        <td><x:out select="description" escapeXml="false"/></td>
    </tr>
    <% i++; %>
    <% if (i >10) break; %>         
  </x:forEach>
</table>
</c:if>
```

I have to display only upto 10 feeds so i have initially declared i as 1 and then i am printing till i+10.
my code works fine the first time,but the second time it is displaying only 1 feed(it is not incrementing).can anyone tell me what can be the problem? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was not incrementing, you would get all the results. What probably is happening is that it remains at value > 10, so it only displays one item. Try resetting `i` before the break

```
<% if (i >10) { i = 1; break; } %>
```

You could do it also using `varStatus`, without scriptlets

```
<c:if test="${status.index lt 10}">
     <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="feedValue[]"  onclick="$('#message').val(this.value);" data-dismiss="modal" value="<x:out select="description" escapeXml="false"/>"></td>
        <td><x:out select="description" escapeXml="false"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:if>
```